# Build file server to upload files from IPhone and Mac using Raspberry Pie

Tags: iphone, raspberry-pi, fileserver, file-storage

Is it possible to build a File storage server using Raspberry Pi 3 to upload files from apple device using Wifi?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe so. Use nginx or Apache to host it and have a PHP or JS script that accepts files from an HTML form and saves them.
For me, Apache is easier to use, but I prefer nginx as it is much faster.
Once you have the server and HTML/PHP/JS set up just navigate to your Pi's IP in Safari. There you go!
You do, however, have limitations. Saving files to an external flash drive is your best option, unless your Pi is only being used as a server. In that case, make sure you `chown` the folder where you would like to save the files to the user that the server uses (`www-data` for nginx, I think it's the same for Apache)
If I was unclear about anything, just let me know!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, can you point me to a tutorial if you know of any ? I'm kind of new to this.

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of any right now. I'll tell you if I find one! Sorry :P